# How to override custom_mail send method in flask-seurity

Tags: python, flask-security

I want to implement flask-security in my project.When user register on app, he will receive mail for confirmation.Then he follow link but it will redirect to base view not override custom view.

Code

```
@app.route('/confirm_demo/<token>')
                @login_required
                def confirm_email_demo(token):
                    print "My Method........................................."
                    try:  
                        email = confirm_token(token)
                    except:
                        flash('The confirmation link is invalid or has expired.', 'danger')
                    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first_or_404()
                    if user.active:
                        flash('Account already confirmed. Please login.', 'success')
                    else:
                        user.active = True
                        user.confirmed_at = datetime.datetime.now()
                        db.session.add(user)
                        db.session.commit()
                        flash('You have confirmed your account. Thanks!', 'success')
                    return redirect(url_for('main.home'))
```